# Storing Rails notifications for the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, instrumentation, middleware

I'm working on some code that unobtrusively instruments Rails using ActiveSupport::Notifications.  However in the callback blocks there's no way to access the current request or the env variable that would give me access to the request_id.

Is there a way I can store this information keyed on the request_id for retrieval later?